# Collapsing a jQuery accordion when clicking a link outside of the accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, session-cookies

I'm using this jQuery accordion menu found here [jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu Plugin](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/getting-started/).  The plugin is working well without much customization.  The feature that I was really looking for that this plugin offers is persistent menu state after a page refresh.  This plugin uses cookies to accomplish this.  On to the problem...

If you click outside the accordion menu the state is still maintained.  I'm trying to figure out a way to collapse the entire menu when a link is clicked outside of the accordion menu.

My first inclination was to find some way to delete or reset the data in state saving cookie when the window.location was equal to a certain URL. (At the moment it I be happy if when returning to the home page that the menu was completely collapsed).

I'm thinking the best solution would be some jQuery that if an  was clicked outside of #Accordion-Navigation was clicked that it would reset the cookie or collapse the menu.

I'm open to anything.

I tried the following with no luck.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
    var siteurl = "http://myhomepageurl.com/index.php";
if (window.location.href == siteurl) {
    jQuery.cookie('dcjq-accordion-1', null, { path: '/'});
    }
});
```

Any suggestions at a more elegant solution would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks for taking the time to have a look in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to do this, just bind an event handler on your html and body element.
If the accordion was clicked you stops the propagation, otherwise you collapse the accordion.

```
$(function () {
  $('html').on('click', collapseAccordion);
  $('body')
    .on('click','.accordion', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() });
});
```

you should make a function `collapseAccordion` that collapses the accordion via an api call.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not following the code properly but wouldn't this collapse the Accordion on any click inside the '.accordion' class?  If so I'm looking for the opposite of this...

Comment: if that _is_ what it does I could change this class to something like '.on-click-collapse-accordion' and then any link I have this class on would cause the "collapseAccordion" function to be called?

Comment: I made a mistake by subselect the `.accordion` element in the clickhandler on the `html` element

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  $('body').mousedown(function (e) { 
    if($(e.target).closest('.accordion').length != 1){
       //click was outside accordion,
       // so close it
    }      
});
```